# Unable to show Json html content data in textview in android

Tags: android, html-content-extraction

Right now i am trying to display images and texts from one html content in text-view in android. Actually i am getting those html contents from json,but the help of below code i can only able to show the available texts like the below image 
[image]

and unable to show the images.Can any one tell me how to display both images and texts from html content?

suggestions please

Thanks for your precious time!..

```
String  htmlcontent = "\u003ch3 style=\"text-align: justify;\"\u003e \u003cspan style=\"color: #800080;\"\u003eJourneys Magazine -                     Sports                          Best of Rage\r\n\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan style=\"color: #800080;\"\u003e New Ireland Journey                     Magazine                     Magazine\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/h3\u003e\r\n\u003cp style=\"text-align: justify;\"\u003e\u003cimg alt=\"\" src=\"http://dev.postcourier.com.pg/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Journeys-NIP_-Front-cover.jpg\" width=\"180\" height=\"335\" /\u003e \u003cimg alt=\"\" src=\"http://dev.postcourier.com.pg/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Sports-Magazine-Cover2.jpg\" width=\"184\" height=\"336\" /\u003e \u003cimg alt=\"\" src=\"http://dev.postcourier.com.pg/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/BOR_front-cvr.jpg\" width=\"184\" height=\"335\" /\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\u003cp style=\"text-align: justify;\"\u003e \u003c/p\u003e";

txt_date.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlcontent));
```

Comment: Why don't you use webview instead of TextView?

Comment: @Chaitu can you please tell me how to set the string value in webview?

Comment: String htmlContent="<Your Html Content"; webview.loadData(htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TextView** is used to show **Text only**.
@Manick you can only show text in TextView, if you want to show the html page(with images and complete page), you have to use a **Webview**, then when you will get the json, you have to save it in .html file, and then give that file to webview to show that page or you can show html content in the Webview by using this example code. html string will be your JSON response.

**Here is the example:-**

```
public class SimpleMusicStream extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);        

        final String mimeType = "text/html";
        final String encoding = "UTF-8";
        String html = "<br /><br />Read the handouts please for tomorrow.<br /><br /><!--homework help homework" +
                "help help with homework homework assignments elementary school high school middle school" +
                "// --><font color='#60c000' size='4'><strong>Please!</strong></font>" +
                "<img src='http://www.homeworknow.com/hwnow/upload/images/tn_star300.gif'  />";


        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please give me atleast one sample for your suggestion?

Comment: I have posted the example code from this link: you can get more idea from here:- 
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/04/display-html-format-text-in-webview.html

Answer (score 1):

String  htmlcontent = "\u003ch3 style=\"text-align: justify;\"\u003e \u003cspan style=\"color: #800080;\"\u003eJourneys Magazine -                     Sports                          Best of Rage\r\n\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan style=\"color: #800080;\"\u003e New Ireland Journey                     Magazine                     Magazine\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/h3\u003e\r\n\u003cp style=\"text-align: justify;\"\u003e\u003cimg alt=\"\" src=\"http://dev.postcourier.com.pg/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Journeys-NIP_-Front-cover.jpg\" width=\"180\" height=\"335\" /\u003e \u003cimg alt=\"\" src=\"http://dev.postcourier.com.pg/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Sports-Magazine-Cover2.jpg\" width=\"184\" height=\"336\" /\u003e \u003cimg alt=\"\" src=\"http://dev.postcourier.com.pg/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/BOR_front-cvr.jpg\" width=\"184\" height=\"335\" /\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n\u003cp style=\"text-align: justify;\"\u003e \u003c/p\u003e";

WebView webView=new WebView(this);
webView.loadData(htmlContent,"text/html","UTF-8");

Thats it

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SimpleMusicStream extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);

        final String mimeType = "text/html";
        final String encoding = "UTF-8";
        final String baseUrl = "http://www.homeworknow.com/";
        String html = "<br /><br />Read the handouts please for tomorrow.<br /><br /><!--homework help homework" +
                "help help with homework homework assignments elementary school high school middle school" +
                "// --><font color='#60c000' size='4'><strong>Please!</strong></font>" +
                "<img src='http://www.homeworknow.com/hwnow/upload/images/tn_star300.gif'  />";


        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, html, mimeType, encoding, "");
    }

}// only thing for show image in webview from html give **base url** of image like this http://www.homeworknow.com/
```