# Display html table in textview in android without using webview

Tags: android, html, eclipse

I know this question is asked number of times but still here I am asking it again. I have json data being fetched in my app. This data is in html format. The other data is being displayed fine in textview the problem occurs when there is a table along with data. All I want is the table to get displayed in proper format.

I have been though various examples and questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032518/unable-to-show-json-html-content-data-in-textview-in-android),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14439657/5084985),the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13189878/5084985), also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032173/how-to-display-html-table-in-androidnot-vebview). These are few links I have been to. I am trying to find answer for this for past few days but every answer mostly suggests using webview or is not getting the desired result.

I can't use webview so isn't there a solution to atleast format table in proper way?

If anyone can help me I will really be thankful. Thank you.

Edit:
this is what I expect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DxWN.png)

Also I can't include webview because webview doesnot fulfil all requirements of my app and textview is displaying everything fine except tables.

Comment: can you show us a picture of what you expect from textview. also why cant you use webview?

Comment: I am also searching for the same. Have you found any solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: I still haven't found a solution , I'm still working on it. I'll post if I find anything useful. If you find an answer please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an library in Github which supports html tables - https://github.com/PrivacyApps/html-textview

Supported tags:

```
<p>
<div> handled exactly like <p>
<br>
<b>
<i>
<strong>
<em> 
<u>
<tt>
<dfn>
<sub>
<sup>
<blockquote>
<cite>
<big>
<small>
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">
<h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>
<a href="...">
<img src="...">
```

Also: 
Extended support by HtmlTextView

```
<ul>
<ol>
<li>
<code>
<center>
<strike>
```

Support for HTML tables

HtmlTextView now supports HTML tables (to a limited extent) by condensing the text into a link which developers are able to render in a native WebView. To take advantage of the feature you'll need to:

We recognize the standard table tags:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>
<td>
```